# problemas para hacer mi sitio web responsivo

Tags: html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

Tengo un problema con mi página web, he creado una sección llamada "sobre nosotros" que está dividida por un párrafo a la izquierda y una foto a la derecha, cuando hago la página web más pequeña, el párrafo se coloca encima del pie de página, aquí está mi código para que lo vean.

```
<section id="pantalla-dividad">
        <div class="izquierda">
            <h1><span class="creative">Web</span><span style="color: 
            #fff">Two</span></h1>
            <P> ACA ESTA EL TEXTO .</P>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="contacto.html" target="_blank">Contactanos</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="derecha"></div>
    </section>
```

```
     body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    
    
    .left{
        background-color: #dce0e5;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 50%;
        
    }
    .right{
        background-image: url(../img/about5.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    #pantalla-dividad{
        display: flex;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 19px;
        line-height: 30px;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tambien haria falta ver tu codigo html para ver como estas usando las clases declaradas en el CSS

Comment: Ya esta puesto el HTML, muchas gracas!

Comment: y el footer que clases usa y su html?

Answer (score 0):

Modifique un poco tu **CSS** para que pruebes que tal:

```
#pantalla-dividad {
 display: flex; 
 /* align-content: space-between; */
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 200px; /* altura importante para su contenido */
} 

.left {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background-color: #dce0e5; 
} 

.right {
 background-image: url(../img/about5.jpg); 
 background-size: cover; 
 background-position: center; 
} 

.left, .right {
 width: 50%; 
 height: 100vw; /* con respecto a #pantalla-dividida */
}
```

Si esto no te funciona, edita tu pregunta especificando más con tu código HTML5 y CSS3.

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad responder solo con codigo, porfavor leer.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer